# Unable to use bluetooth device in Debian Jessie 8.6

Tags: debian, audio, bluetooth

I recently installed `Debian Jessie 8.6` as a clean install.
The only thing I kept was my `HOME` partition.

After the installation finished, I wanted to connect my bluetooth headphones but they couldn't be paired.

Checking the status of the service: `service bluetooth status`

```
Dec 18 13:03:55 user-laptop bluetoothd[512]: Bluetooth daemon 5.23
Dec 18 13:03:58 user-laptop systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Dec 18 13:03:58 user-laptop bluetoothd[512]: Starting SDP server
Dec 18 13:03:58 user-laptop bluetoothd[512]: Bluetooth management interface 1.6 initialized
Dec 18 13:03:59 user-laptop bluetoothd[512]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Dec 18 13:03:59 user-laptop bluetoothd[512]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
```

I tried without success:

1. Purging all bluetooth packages and installing them again.
2. Following [Thorsten's message](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=757292#17) from the Debian mailing list.

   > - bluetoothctl
   > - scan on
   > - pair
   > - unblock
   > - connect
3. Installed `pulseaudio` bluetooth packages and repeated previous step.
   (and removed them again)

In `step #2`, the device is paired and connected successfully, but the sound is still going out through the laptop, instead of the headphones.

The strange thing is that this worked with **Jessie 8.4 out of the box**.

What could the problem be?

---

**Bluetooth installed packages:** `dpkg -l | grep blue`

```
ii  blueman                               1.99~alpha1-1+deb8u1                 amd64        Graphical bluetooth manager
ii  bluetooth                             5.23-2                               all          Bluetooth support
ii  bluez                                 5.23-2+b1                            amd64        Bluetooth tools and daemons
ii  bluez-firmware                        1.2-3                                all          Firmware for Bluetooth devices
ii  bluez-obexd                           5.23-2+b1                            amd64        bluez obex daemon
ii  bluez-tools                           0.2.0~20140808-3                     amd64        Set of tools to manage Bluetooth devices for linux
ii  libbluetooth3:amd64                   5.23-2+b1                            amd64        Library to use the BlueZ Linux Bluetooth stack
```

Comment: Welcome to U& L ? Does the `bluez` package is installed on your system?

Comment: Yes! I will update the post with all the bluetooth related packages.

Comment: Do you use a gamepad over bluetooth like PS3 controller?

Comment: Install `pavucontrol` package then run it as user ,From the *output device* choose headphone under the Port menu

Comment: @Bahamut It's a pair of Philiphs headphones.

Comment: @GAD3R Didn't work. The headphones appear as an output device, but the sound is still going through the `Built-In Analog Stereo` device.
In the Port menu of that device, there is an entry for the headphones with the tag `unplugged`.

Comment: yes, in another Forum someone has Problems with USB-Speakers, because he uses a PS3 controller at the same time.  Change the `ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd` in `/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service`  to `ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --noplugin=sap` this disable the plugin after that `systemctl daemon-reexec` and  restart the bluetooth service with `systemctl restart bluetooth`

Comment: @AdriC.S. what is your desktop environment ?

Comment: @Bahamut Yep. That did the trick, although I still have to select the headphones manually in `pavucontrol` every time I connect them,

Comment: @GAD3R I'm using `xfce4`.

Comment: Take a Look under `/etc/bluetooth/audio` or similiar. I have no bluetooth so I don't know the exact name.